# How to convert a large series of .img files to a gif with image magick (IM) from command line

Tags: linux, image-processing, command-line, imagemagick, remote-access

I have a set of 1800 images (16Mb each, of the .img type).

I would like to convert them into a gif from the command line as I am remotely connected to the server they are stored on and it is not feasible to download all of them (for use with local programs). I cannot install  new programs on the server, but it has imagemagick installed (IM).

When I try the standard command: `convert -resize 20% -delay 5 -loop 0 /pwd/*.img output.gif`

I get an error of`no decode delegate for this image format IMG @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.`
`convert: no images defined d263g_07.gif @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3257.`

Is there a way to handle img formats at all in IM? It seems in their documentation it is not a supported filetype, but other googling says .img images are very near bitmaps in format. I wonder if there is a piping option or something that would let me accomplish my goal?

**EDIT**: These are images straight from a CMOS detector of diffraction patterns (x-ray crystallography).
Also I just found a hidden imageJ executable as well. So if that offers options not available to IM, that could be a solution as well.

Comment: Please clarify what your IMG images are - what application do they come from and what do they contain - vector graphics, bitmap graphics, disk images...?

Comment: I think these files are [GEM VDI raster](http://justsolve.archiveteam.org/wiki/GEM_Raster) images. [NetPBM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net) should have a `gemtopnm` utility that can integrate with ImageMagick (if IM was compiled to with NetPBM support).

Comment: Cool! I used to love GemDraw back in around 1988. Do you (@Lyk) have a sample file you could provide for testing please - probably via Dropbox or some file-sharing service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a first attempt, I think you will need something along these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *img; do
    cat "$f" | convert -depth 16 -size 2952x2820+3072 gray:- -resize 800x -normalize -depth 8 MIFF:-
done | convert - -delay 80 result.gif
```

You may need to decrease the quality, or sub-sample frames or further reduce the size to get an acceptable GIF size. To decrease the size, change it to `-resize 500x` maybe. Or to reduce the quality (and therefore the size), add in `-quality 75%` or similar. See how you get on and report back!

So, save the above in a file called `go` in your HOME (login) directory, then execute the following command (just once) to make it executable:

```
chmod +x $HOME/go
```

Then, go to the directory where the images are stored, e.g.:

```
cd /some/place/images
```

and run the script by typing:

```
$HOME/go
```

After a while it will hopefully finish and the animated GIF will be called `result.gif`. If you still have problems, copy each line below as is and then paste them, one line at a time into your Terminal:

```
for f in *img; do cat "$f" | 
convert -depth 16 -size 2952x2820+3072 gray:- -resize 800x -normalize -depth 8 MIFF:- done |
convert - -delay 80 result.gif
```

I don't know what viewers you have installed, but you could try:

```
feh results.gif
```

**Output as movie/video**

If you want to try outputting a video/movie rather than an animated GIF, you should be able to do it with `ffmpeg`. The command will look pretty much like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *img; do
    cat "$f" | convert -depth 16 -size 2952x2820+3072 gray:- -resize 800x -normalize -depth 8 ppm:-
done | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -framerate 30 -i - -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4
```

**Original Answer**

I think we may have to do this answer stepwise... does this look like your image:

[image]

I got it like this:

```
convert -depth 16 -size 2952x2820+3072 gray:- -normalize a.jpg < ~/Desktop/d263g-07_1_0001.img
```

Comment: Yes, that does. So can we then pipe that normalization into a jpg into the conversion into a gif without having to save every jpg?

Comment: Yes, hang on a bit... do all 1800 have to go into a single GIF? That will be rather large.

Comment: Ideally, yes. If there were a way to skip (preferably without having to write a full script) to every 10/100 frames that would also be sufficient. Also, downsampling to a lower resolution is an option - they don't have to stay at the current.

Comment: Sorry for the noob question, but I'm a rookie Linux user, and I'm not sure what to do with your answer. I believe it is a small script given the 'shebang'. Do I need to save that as a file (and if so what extension do I give it?) and then execute it somehow to achieve the result?

Comment: I tried putting it into a .sh file and changing the appropriate paths then executing with ./scriptname.sh, but I got permission denied. Which, isn't surprising as they probably don't want random users ssh'ing into the server having the power to write scripts...? So it may not be possible to do it via an executed script. Not sure if I can edit permissions or something

Comment: I think you missed the `chmod +x SCRIPTNAME` part. Failing that, you can copy the script and paste it into the terminal. just put a `\\` at the end of each line.

Comment: It worked! Using the go and chmod method. Thanks so much! It took a very long time to make, though even at 500x and 50% quality. I'd attach the result gif but it's 227MB :D. I guess I should also look into compressing it as a movie or something. The end goal of this was to have a quick script that I could run this on for many datasets (i.e. 10x1800 image datasets) that would produce a gif for analyzing quality.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. I have added a section on how to make a video/movie if you want to give that a try. Let us know if it works and if the file size is smaller. Good luck with your project!

Comment: I am unable to try the video version, as ffmpeg is not loaded on the server. However, I've found a sligtly cumbersome way of accomplishing the task which is to create the full gif (even at 5-10% quality they look good, but still over 100Mb). Then to simply record the 'high' quality one with another screen recording software (which makes a webm or gif itself) at a much smaller file size (<5Mb). Here's a link to see what the final product looks like. https://gfycat.com/ClearcutComfortableHoneybee

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for sharing.